# Dismissviewcontroller and perform segue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

I need to go to another viewcontroller with `performSegueWithIdentifier` but I also need to remove the viewcontroller I'm currently in. How can I do this, I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"next" sender:self];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

//tried the other way, but it doesn't work either
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"next" sender:self];
```

It looks like there isn't any easy way to do this?
I have 4 viewcontrollers, they are connected like this, and I want to go from gameover to highscore.

```
menu-->game----->gameover
menu-->highscore
```

Comment: What's your view layout? You're trying to dismiss a modally presented UIViewController and performing a segue that goes where? Also what do you mean by doesn't work? Does it crash? Does it fail silently?

Comment: Ultimately this sounds like poor design, are you using modal or push segues? It sounds like you should be using push segues then you don't need to worry about dismissing the view controller.

Comment: @Gabro It says "Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!". And it performs the segue but if I go back, the viewcontroller is still there. So it doesn't dismiss.

Comment: @mkral I'm using modal. I cant use push because its a game, so it wouldn't look nice. So basically I have 4 vc:s 1 menu from wich you can choose to play or see highscore. And then when you play I want to go to highscore, how would you do that?
menu-->game-->gameover-->highscore;menu-->highscore

Comment: I would still use push just hide the navigation bar. then you can pop the pushes and specifically popToRootViewController from highscore

Comment: @mkral Oh, I didn't know that you could hide the navigation bar. Do I do that in interface builder? I will look at it now

Comment: in your first VC put `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES` it will stay hidden as long as you use the same NavigationController

Comment: @mkral I did it in interface builder but I guess both works great, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
UIViewController *parentController = self.presentingViewController;
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){
    [parentController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"next" sender:self];
}];
```

Comment: I tested that before, but it doesn't work because you remove the viewcontroller before it can perform the segue. But it needs the viewcontroller to perform the segue, so the segue never gets called.

Comment: I haven't tested it but it should still be able to perform the segue since it won't be removed. But if you tried it, then it's probably a different reason why it won't work.

Comment: Well, I can't test it right now either, because I changed so now I use a navigation controller. But I'll try your answer next time!

Comment: Works for me. Missing closing brace on last line.

Comment: I use for navigation controller based app. [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this is what I did to resolve if anyone comes here looking for answers.

```
//In viewController that is being dismissed
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"callSegue" object:self];
}];


//In viewController being presented
//in viewDidLoad:
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(gotoNewView)
                                                 name: @"callSegue"
                                               object: nil];

-(void)gotoNewView {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToPerform" sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I realized I should use a push segue instead. 
The New VC will dismiss them both at once.

Answer (score 0):

Even better:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^(void)
{
 // Perform the segue here.
}];
```